# Trigger a event at dynamic time in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am building a Cart microservice in Spring Boot, where each cart will have an expiration datetime set by an admin user. What is the best way to trigger an event to expire the cart after the defined datetime?

I imagine that a periodic task would not work, as a very short period would compromise the performance of the system, and a very long period would leave room for the user to operate on an expired cart that has not yet been picked up by the task.

Setting a trigger can still cause errors since it is possible that the trigger changes the cart in the database to expired while an instance is already being updated by the system, i.e. a concurrency problem. But it may still not be so critical.

Any recommendations? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the solution of delay message queue such as RocketMQ. You service produces delayed message, and RocketMQ is responsible for delay sending message to the consumer. You could refer to [Delayed Message Sending](https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/4.x/producer/04message3/).